# Python: How to format PYODBC Query Output

Tags: format, pyodbc

I am querying from a database using PYODBC as below:

```
cursor.execute("SELECT Distinct country from dbo.purchases")

for row in cursor.fetchall():
    print row
```

The Result of the script is as so:

```
('Taiwan', )
('Japan', )
```

How can I format the pyodbc output query to just:

```
Taiwan
Japan
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result is a tuple, so `print row[0]`.